# Slice byte-stream into bit pieces

Tags: programming, rs232

I receive byte data from a RS-232 device with `Serial.read();`. Now I need to slice this down in bit-pieces:

- value1: 15bits
- value2: 7bits
- value3: 9bits
- value4: 12bits
- and so on

Data from the stream (switch them around for better understanding):

- Byte 1: 00101100 => 00110100 (least significant byte first)
- Byte 2: 10011011 => 11011001
- Byte 3: 00110011 => 11001100
- Byte 4: 11101000 => 00010111
- Byte 5: 01001100 => 00110010
- Byte 6: 01100111 => 11100110

Now the least significant is first.

- value1: `00110100.1101100[1]` => 6956
  Need to cut of the last bit of the second byte
- value2: `1.110011[00]` => 103
  Add the last bit of the second byte and cut off the last two bits of the third byte
- value3: `00.0001011[1]` => 416
  Add the last two bits of the third byte and cut off the last bit of the fourth byte
- value4: `1.00110010.111[00110]` => 3737
  Add the last bit of the fourth byte and cut off the last 5 bits of the fifth byte

Now the question: How do I realize this from programming side. I'm lost.

Comment: If the records are byte aligned you could use a struct with bit-fields and let the compiler do the work. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_bit_fields.htm

Comment: Another alternative is to define a BitStream class that operates on a Stream (Serial). Typical member function would be uint16_t read(uint8_t bits). The class would have to buffer any remaining bits for the next read, etc. http://www.drdobbs.com/bitstream-parsing-in-c/184402014

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a year old question with no answers.

Comment: @LookAlterno But this one has an answer. It is/was edited into the question. I have now put that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

**Note: This is an answer that OP originally edited into his question.**

---

I gather the data into an array of bytes `data[125]`.

Then I gather the relevant bytes per value and stack them together:

```
long var = (data[4]<<8) + (data[3]);
```

I shift them so the relevant bytes start first

```
var=var>>3;
```

Afterwards I mask them with the RIGHT mask

```
var=var & 0xFF;
```

For the example in my question:

```
long var = (data[1]<<8) + (data[0]); // I need two bytes  
var=var>>1; // shift them to the right one bit  
var=var & 0x7FFF; // mask it with "0111 1111 1111 1111"
```

Comment: Good work gre_gor!